# maximization program with a discount factor in monopoly with learning by doing

Tags: microeconomics, self-study

I would know something about the multiproduct monopoly. In the case with independent demands and costs dependents, it is in the case with only 1 physical good sold out of 2 periods. For example (learning by doing).

$$q_i = D_i(p_i); C_1(q_1); C_2(q_1,q2)$$
with $$\frac{\partial C_2}{\partial q_1} < 0$$

I want to write the maximization program assuming that there is a discount factor d.   But I have no idea how I can do it

Thanks in advance.

So I did it for the moment, but I'm not sure at all

$$p_1D_1(p_1)-C_1(D_1(p_1))+\delta[p_2D_2(p_2)-C_2(D_2(p_2),D_1(p_1))]$$

Comment: Could you please show us your attempt first? Even if you don't know how it is usually done you can make an attempt

Comment: so, Can I got a tip ?